# BigQuery: query for GROUP BY and AVG

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to aggregate `covermean` mean by `FARM`, `STAND` and `DATE` variables using a SQL query in BigQuery. In the Editor I try to make`

```
SELECT 
FARM,
STAND,
DATE,
AVG(covermean) AS covermean 
FROM "myDB" 
GROUP BY FARM, STAND, DATE
ORDER BY FARM, STAND, DATE
```

But the mean value doesn't change (eg. for the first STAND variable `76.0478`), but must be changed by FARM, STAND and DATE.

[image: testBQ]

Please any help with it?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected data? Just so the community can easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: yes, please show some of the raw input data